Annotation Inheritance on Microprofile @OpenAPIDefinition
I want to create a custom @org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.annotations.OpenAPIDefinition but somehow the inheritance is not working.
I thought that both should be the same:

// MyAPIDefinition.java

@OpenAPIDefinition(info = @Info(title = "bla", version = "1.0") /** with licence and so on**/)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@Documented
public @interface MyAPIDefinition {}

// and MyApplication.java

@MyAPIDefinition
public class MyApplication extends Application {}



and

// MyApplication.java

@OpenAPIDefinition(info = @Info(title = "bla", version = "1.0") /** with licence and so on**/)
public class MyApplication extends Application {}

But the first solution will not add the info to /openapi, while the second solution is working like expected.
Environment:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>microprofile-openapi-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


Docker quay.io/wildfly/wildfly:28.0.1.Final-jdk17

with <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.openapi-smallrye"/>
and <subsystem xmlns="urn:wildfly:microprofile-openapi-smallrye:1.0"/>
no custom application.properties



So my question is:

Have I done something wrong? Is it an bug?

If any example repository is required please let me know.
